# CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

Returns an error

> CS0029
>   C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'

That function is used here:

```
gameTimer.Tick += UpdateScreen();
```

The function is:

```
private void UpdateScreen()
{
    if(Settings.GameOver == true)
    {
        if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Enter))
        {
            StartGame();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Right) && Settings.direction != Direction.Left)
            Settings.direction = Direction.Right;
        else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Left) && Settings.direction != Direction.Right)
            Settings.direction = Direction.Left;
        else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Up) && Settings.direction != Direction.Down)
            Settings.direction = Direction.Up;
        else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Down) && Settings.direction != Direction.Up)
            Settings.direction = Direction.Down;

        MovePlayer();
    }

    pbCanvas.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: `UpdateScreen()` is *execution* when `UpdateScreen` is *method* itself; the right syntax is `gameTimer.Tick += UpdateScreen;`. We assign `Tick` to the *method*, not to method's *result* (which is `void`)

Answer (score 14):

You should assign the method **without** parentheses, because you're trying to assign the result of the method (which it doesn't have because of the `void`)

Also the method must have the right arguments.

```
gameTimer.Tick += UpdateScreen;

private void UpdateScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or if you don't want to change the methods arguments. You could use a lambda expression. (which creates a new delegate that calls the UpdateScreen method. *(wrapper)*

```
gameTicker.Tick += (s, ee) => UpdateScreen();
```

Answer (score 3):

No need of parentheses. You can also do this:

```
gameTimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { UpdateTimer(s, ev); }
```

And fix the UpdateTimer method.

Or you can also do the following:

```
gameTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(UpdateTimer);
```

More on delegates here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

More on DispatchTimer here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer#Windows_UI_Xaml_DispatcherTimer_Tick

Comment: This `gameTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(UpdateTimer);` doesn't work. `UpdateTimer` doesn't exists and the `UpdateScreen` doesn't have an object as argument,    `gameTimer.Tick += (s, ev) => { UpdateTimer(s, ev); }` same issue.